# Home-Assistant (Automation) Websockets server monitoring another server?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, websocket, server, home-automation

In an attempt to utilize my web-connected security system with Home-Assistant ([home-assistant.io](http://home-assistant.io)), I did some research on it’s web interface, and it looks like it uses websockets to imitate keypad presses.

I would like Home-Assistant, which typically functions as a Websockets **server** itself to be able to monitor/control the security system by acting as the client(?), but it seems like all the documentation seems to show HA as the server and not as the client.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the HASS websocket documentation.  You can send commands to services and also subscribe to the websocket server.  This should give you the ability to talk to HASS by sending a service call to any of the registered components (such as zwave door sensors or siren).   Does that make sense?

https://home-assistant.io/developers/websocket_api/